# Solutions to $\partial_{t} \lvert \phi(x,y,z,t) \rvert^{2} = 0$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, complex-numbers, partial-derivative

I have a *very* basic question about the modulus squared of a probability density function, or any complex function really. Say we have a complex function

$$\phi(x,y,z,t) = \phi_{r}(x,y,z,t) + i \phi_{i}(x,y,z,t)$$

and its complex conjugate $\phi^{*}$ (where $\phi_{r}, \phi_{i}$ represent the real and complex parts, respectively) that satisfies the equation

$$\partial_{t} \lvert \phi \rvert^{2} = \partial_{t} (\phi \phi^{*}) = 0$$

i.e $\lvert \phi \rvert^{2}$ is *independent* of the coordinate $t$.

My question is

> Does this necessarily mean that the solution is an *exponential function* i.e $\phi \propto a^{i \omega(t)}$ for some
> argument $\omega$ and some $a \in \mathbb{R}$ (i.e $a
>  = \exp$)? Or are there other possible solutions?

I realise that I have not included a 'radial' component which can be dependent on $(x,y,z)$ and I am aware that the argument $\omega$ can also be dependent on these same spatial coordinates. I am not concerned with these parts. My question is about the explicit form of the of the $t$ dependent component.

Integrating the equation and using the definition of the modulus squared, we have

$$\varphi(x,y,z) = \lvert \phi \rvert^{2} = \sqrt{\phi_{r}^{2} + \phi_{i}^{2}}$$

which has the obvious solution $(\phi_{r}, \phi_{i}) = \varphi(x,y,z) (\cos(\omega(t)), \sin(\omega(t)))$. However, I was wondering if this was the only solution. Note that this ansatz includes the possibility that $\omega$ could possibly be zero so that $\phi$ itself is actually independent of $t$.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(it seems you have basically ignored the presence of $x,y,z$ so I will too.)

A complex number $\phi$ is completely determined by polar coordinates $(\rho,\omega) \in [0,\infty)\times [-\pi,\pi)$: $\phi = \rho \exp(i\omega)$, and conversely one can determine $\rho=|\phi|$ and $\omega$ from $\phi$ with arctan and the real/imaginary parts.

The same holds for arbitrary (e.g. non smooth) functions of a parameter $t$, by using the previous at each $t$; $\phi(t) = \rho(t) \exp(i\omega(t))$ for a unique $\rho(t) = |\phi(t)|$ and not so unique $\omega(t)$. The quantity $|\phi(t)|^2$ is precisely $\rho(t)^2$, and asking this to be $t$ independent of course means that $\rho(t) \equiv \rho_0$ a constant. Thus the function must be of the form $\phi(t) = \rho_0 \exp(i\omega(t))$.

You lose a little if you set up the problem differently. If you do not ensure that $\rho\ge 0$ then you can replace $\rho_0$ with $\rho_0 \epsilon(t)$ where $\epsilon:\mathbb R \to \{-1,+1\}$ is arbitrary.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear. I am looking for _functions_ that are different from an exponential. Obviously, as you have stated, any argument $\theta$ that is $t$ dependent statisfies the equation irrespective of the form of $\theta$, but this is due to the fact that the solution is an exponential. I'll make an edit to the question. I actually thought I had put this in my post but I must have edited it out.

Comment: I only noticed the downvote when an upvote registered as -8, but I don't see any issues with the answer. *c'est la vie!*

Comment: Just so you know, I didn't downvote and I can't understand why anyone did either. Your answer is exactly what I expected was the case. I will most likely give you the bounty, upvote and accept your answer once the two days are up, I'm just going to wait until the end of the bounty period ends to see if anyone has anything else to add.

Comment: There is no need to guarantee such things for me, if a better answer comes then that is good and you should accept that. would simply prefer the vote explained